# Where can I get the NaturalDocs Maven plugin?

Tags: maven

The maven configuration mentioned in [the Usage section of the Natural Docs Maven Plugin site](http://mojo.codehaus.org/naturaldocs-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.naturaldocs</groupId>
<artifactId>naturaldocs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

However; I can't seem to find any version in any Maven repository including [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/) or the [Snapshot repo](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/org/codehaus/mojo/).

I was able to find what seems like the initial version attached to [this Mojo plugin submission](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1579) but it only includes source, and while it's nice to look at I don't wish to compile it for use myself.

Comment: http://mojo.codehaus.org/using-sandbox-plugins.html But I don't see it there, so you may need to build and deploy it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the source archive that you referenced and unzip it in a convenient spot.

From that folder, run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Assuming that runs without issue, run:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=target\naturaldocs-maven-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.naturaldocs -DartifactId=naturaldocs-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Assuming that runs fine, check the local deploy works as expected by including the pom reference in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.naturaldocs</groupId>
    <artifactId>naturaldocs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If your project build without issue, then deploy it to your local Maven repo by running:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar-Drepository=extNonFree -Durl=scpexe://maven.your-company.com/your-serverpath/maven/proximity/ext-non-free/storage -Dfile=target\naturaldocs-maven-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.naturaldocs -DartifactId=naturaldocs-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Or have one of your local Maven admins deploy the pom and jar manually.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping to find a location for the plugin binary, but this will do for now.